# What does Machine Learning Paradigms means, and what are they?

Tags: machine-learning

Please, help me to properly answer the following **(main) question**:

> What does machine learning paradigms means? And, what are they?

I tried to answer this questions myself, but two completely different answers come up when searching for it, they are represented by the following links:

- https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/learning-paradigms-in-machine-learning-146ebf8b5943
- https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-five-major-paradigms-of-machine-learning

I understand that in order to answer the question above, we would also need to answer this **additional question**:

> Which of these two links is the proper answer for the question above?

Also, I was wondering how come those two very close terms, on those links, could have what seems to be different meanings. Hence, I also have this **second additional question**:

> Is the term "machine learning paradigms" actually different from "learning paradigms in machine learning"?

Comment: I just edited my question, I hope it's is clear now.

Comment: @Sean-owen, Is this question now clear?